# How to retrieve records from mysql table using select option ONCHANGE event

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

I have one table like

**mst_city**

```
ID    City         Country
1     Pune         India
2     london       UK
3     California   US
4     Dubai        UAE
```

**PHP**

```
<select name="city_select">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mst_city`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {                                                      
        echo "<option value= ". $row['id'] ." selected='selected'> " . $row['city'] ." </option>";
?>
</select>
<input type="date" name="country" class="text" value=""/>
```

How can i change country name in textbox when change city in select option.

Comment: `mysql_**` functions are officially **deprecated**. You can choose `mysqli_**` functions or `Mysqli` class or `PDO` class. I recommend you the last one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle the `change` event in jQuery by performing an AJAX request upon each city selection change:

```
$('input[name=city_select]').on('change', function() {
     //Do the AJAX request for country here, like:
     $.get("getCountryByCity.php?cityId="+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
          //Set the retrieved country:
          $('input[name=country]').val(data);
});
```

In addition, your PHP code should be like this for querying the counrty from mysql by the city-id:

```
<?php
    $countryQuery = mysql_query("SELECT Country FROM `mst_city` WHERE ID = "+ $_GET['cityId']);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($countryQuery);
    echo $row[0];
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

one you can create a javascript array to do so, and then use it on change property.

Second you can use AJAX to find country name on run time and feed it to the input box.

Comment: also as your table is not so big you can use <br /> $('.city_select').change(function(){$('.country').fadeOut('slow').load('reload.php?pid='+pid).fadeIn("slow")});<br /> just wrote it not tested.

Comment: and then in above reload.php you can create a dynamic input box which will replace the original with fad effects

Comment: thanx but how can i get country name from mysql?

Comment: in reload.php you can write a mysql query for ex "select Country from mst_city where id = '2'" then create a input box with value return from above query